# How to compute a language model with word2vec tool?

Tags: theano, word2vec, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a neural network language model and it seems that word2vec tool by Mikolov et al is a good tool for this purpose. I tried that but it just produces word representations.
Does anybody know how i can produce a language model by that tool or any other reasonable deep learning framework?

Comment: I use opennlp right now.

Comment: Now i know that you can't build a Neural Network Language Model with word2vec, thanks to Phyrox. So what i need is a deep learning tool with an easy to use feature for building language models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doc2Vec implemented in Gensim does the job. The trick is that they use the document ID as a context word, which is present in all window sizes of all the words in the document.

Code is [here in Python/Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html)

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Research has released a toolkit for language modelling with word2vec-style vectors. You can find it [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/rnn/).

Answer (score 2):

`word2vec` is a tool to represent a single word (o a group of words) as a numerical vector. So it is not directly related to a language model.

To generate a Language model you can use the [MITLM](https://code.google.com/p/mitlm/) to do it. For example you can create a N-gram model using the corpus `Lectures.txt` with this command:

```
estimate-ngram -text Lectures.txt -write-lm Lectures.lm
```

A great tutorial can be found [here](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/cgi-bin/wiki/view/SLS/MITLMTutorial).

Comment: Yes but my goal is to stick with Neural Network Language Models specially those which are very close to state of the art methods and have easy to run framework.

Comment: Actually, word2vec learns a neural language model and then discards its predictive powers while only keeping the internal representations (embeddings) of the target word.

Comment: Indeed, you throw away the output layer while keeping the hidden layer weights